# Get background color in array?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get an element's background color as an array with red, green and blue in different items.

Right now I'm doing this:

```
var color = item.css("background-color");
```

Which returns an rgb string "rgb(0,0,0)". How do I get the color as an array or turn the string into one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var rgb = color.replace('rgb(', '').replace(')','' ).split(',').map(Number);
```

Comment: You might want to map then to numbers.

Comment: That is `.replace('rgb(', '').replace(')','' ).split(',').map(Number)`

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Ty sir updated , i missed that :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `slice` and `split`

```
color = color.slice(4,-1).split(',');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/nH58s/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var color = color.replace('rgb(', '').replace(')', '').split(',');
```

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/QZuz9/)

Answer (score 0):

```
function getColor(element) {
  return $(element).css('background-color').replace('rgb(', '').replace(')','' ).split(',');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
color = "rgb(0,0,0)";
color = color.match(/\d+/g);
```